# Import existing ~/.ivy2 repository into Nexus

Tags: maven, ivy, nexus

I have a legacy Ivy2 repository that's a few years old. Some of the artifacts in there aren't on the various Maven repositories (e.g. Typesafe, Sonatype, Maven Central) anymore.

I can point to it with [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) like so:

```
 sbt -v -sbt-version 0.11.3 -ivy /path/to/.ivy2
```

...but IntelliJ or Eclipse aren't this flexible (at least not to me). E.g., I can tell IntelliJ where a local Maven repository is, but not a local Ivy2 repository.

I was hoping to set up a local Nexus instance, but now the question is: **how do I import the Ivy2 repository into Nexus?**

Answer (score 0):

Nexus does not support the ivy repository format. You will have to resort to getting Nexus up and running and starting to proxy everything you need for your builds you can find out there and then migrate the few last missing ones manually into the repository.

Keep in mind that you will be using a Maven repository format, which will work across tools like Maven, Gradle, sbt and ivy.